# does doubleclick support openRTB?

Tags: ads

does DoubleClick exchange support openRTB protocol?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. AdX has its [own version](https://developers.google.com/ad-exchange/rtb/) of RTB protocol based on [protobuff](https://developers.google.com/ad-exchange/rtb/downloads/realtime-bidding-proto.txt).

Answer (score 5):

Google Ad Exchange uses protobuf over HTTP Post and has it's own models.
However, they've now released [openrtb-doubleclick](https://github.com/google/openrtb-doubleclick) that will allow you to easily convert their requests to standard OpenRTB ones and vice versa.

If using maven you can use

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.doubleclick</groupId>
        <artifactId>doubleclick-openrtb</artifactId>
        <version>0.6.5</version>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 2):

There is now OpenRTB and DoubleClick mapper by Google [on Github](https://github.com/google/openrtb-doubleclick).

Answer (score 1):

Actually 01/07/2016 DoubleClick accepts OpenRTB 2.3 ;)

With a hard limit of 5k QPS - added by @Aivaras

Just for the people that land here and this answer is not good anymore ;)

Comment: DoubleClick OpenRTB 2.3 has a hard limit of 5k QPS

Comment: true, but they are open to upgrade that limit it's what suport told me a few days algo.
I suppose that you won't get same like with proto because they need to sell his platform, but since almost all people runs with ORTB they have to do something.

Answer (score 0):

The openrtb-doubleclick library was a good start (and will continue to be available), with the major caveat that it's Java specific. But we're now working on native support for the OpenRTB protocol; pre-announcement here:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/openrtb-dev/lNnOQKLfyhU

This is in private beta at this time but we hope to have the GA release later this year.